# Better Visualization for Correlation Plots

Tags: correlation, python, data-visualization, references

I'm currently working on an analysis of correlated variables involving +20 variables. I can create correlation (triangle) plots and that is quite helpful but I am wondering what other kinds of data visualization tools might exist for looking at correlations and biases in many variables. A reference to some Python libraries would also be quite useful.

Comment: There are (at least) two R packages on CRAN for helping with visualizing correlation matrices: corrplot, Correlplot

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen You've just talked about R to a Python user, that's probably like Satanism to him!

Answer (score 0):

I always find [horizontal barcharts](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barh.html) to be very informative when looking at how all variables are correlated to a single variable

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/321053)